# Dummy variable reference category

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, categorical-encoding

As part of my thesis, I am exploring the effect of firm owner type  on research and development, which is a ratio.  I have a dummy variable of company owner type with 10 categories e.g. Bank, Corporate etc. In my estimates in Stata, I use factor notation, and I have to choose one category as reference. In my case, I use the most frequent owner type, however I'm an not quite sure if that is correct and there is  really nothing in the literature about this, which is confusing since many seem to use dummy variables for owner type.  This is my first struggle.

Additionally, as I understand it, I have to refer to my estimated coefficients with respect to the reference category. So, if Bank, X1, is positive and significant, this means the coefficient is the relationship compared to the base-level owner type say, X2? But I cannot comment on the relation X1 and Y? And I dont know the effect base-level and Y since it is omitted?